# How to use correctly global variables inside if/elif conditions (python)?

Tags: python, if-statement, global

I have this code:
When i change the variables value it gives me NameError: name 'y' is not defined
How can I solve?

```
def a():

    if 5 == 5:
    
       global x
       x = 39
       return True

    elif 6 == 6:

       global y 
       y = 3 
       return True




def b():


    if x == 3:
        print("ok")

    elif y == 3:
        print("no")
    
a()
b()
```

Comment: because `y` won't ever be defined.

Comment: Correct! But how can I solve?

Comment: ... Define it somewhere, or don't try and read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning Ture in the first if statement and the declaration of y is within an elif statement, these two things prevent `y` from ever being defined

```
def a():
    check_1 = False
    check_2 = False

    if 5 == 5:
    
       global x
       x = 39
       check_1 = True

    if 6 == 6:
       global y
       y = 3
       check_2 = True

    return (check_1 and check_2)


def b():

    if x == 3:
        print("ok")

    elif y == 3:
        print("no")
    
a()
b()
```

will output

```
no
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about if i need the "return True" in both if statments? Because in my real code I have a while loop, like: While True: a() : break

Comment: so both if statements must be met else return False?

Comment: I need that only one if statment is necessary for breaking the loop,  when condition is met

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `y` is never defined:

One way to fix it is:

```
def a():
    if 5 == 5:
       global x
       x = 39

    if 6 == 6:
       global y 
       y = 3 

def b():
    if x == 3:
        print("ok")

    elif y == 3:
        print("no")
    
a()
b()
```

Comment: the `return True` in the first `if` statement will prevent `y` being defined

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, missed it.